# Cannot get the data from split and whitespace trim

Tags: split, whitespace

I am trying to read data and then split them.
There are total 4 columns of valid `data(numbers)`, so I used `strip()` and `split(maxsplit=4)` to trim out whitespaces.
I cannot get the whole dataset, instead I see only one 'check' printed (which means somethings not working out)
However, I cannot possibly understand what is wrong with this code.
Please save me.

```
THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
filename = os.path.join(THIS_FOLDER, '1D_Profile.txt')

x, y, void_1, void_2 = [], [], [], []

with open(filename) as data:
for line in data:
    line = line.strip()
    x = x.append(float(line.split(maxsplit=4)[0]))
    y = y.append(float(line.split(maxsplit=4)[1]))
    void_1 = void_1.append(float(line.split(maxsplit=4)[2]))
    void_2 = void_2.append(float(line.split(maxsplit=4)[-1]))
    print('check')
```

This is the first 6 lines of my original data (saved in txt format)

```
 1.0536544e+00   0.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0042425e+00
 1.0526175e+00   0.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0042427e+00
 1.0515805e+00   1.1696509e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0042429e+00
 1.0505435e+00   2.7503487e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0042429e+00
 1.0495065e+00   4.1166442e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0042429e+00
 1.0484695e+00   5.9161777e+00   1.0000000e+00   1.0042429e+00
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out by myself, the answer was ...
The original:

```
    x = x.append(float(line.split(maxsplit=4)[0]))
    y = y.append(float(line.split(maxsplit=4)[1]))
    void_1 = void_1.append(float(line.split(maxsplit=4)[2]))
    void_2 = void_2.append(float(line.split(maxsplit=4)[-1]))
```

I changed as follows:

```
    x.append(float(line.split(maxsplit=4)[0]))
    y.append(float(line.split(maxsplit=4)[1]))
    void_1.append(float(line.split(maxsplit=4)[2]))
    void_2.append(float(line.split(maxsplit=4)[-1]))
```

However I cannot understand why this solves the problem.
Anybody can explain?